# React change view and then scroll to element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to link from one view to another and then scroll to a specific element. I'm not intrested in any animations, only want to have the element in view. The link from one view to another is done through react router.

I guess I could somehow create references on the elements I want to scroll to and pass them to the other view, but don't know if that's the correct approach?

A simple example. (Not working, but hopefully you understand what I want to achieve)

```
const ViewOne = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // From react-router v6
  return (
    <p onClick={() => 
    {
      navigate("ViewTwo"); 
      // What more do I have to add? 
    }}>
      Link to section two, in view two
    </p>
  );
}

export default ViewOne;
```

```
const ViewTwo = () => {
return (
  <>
    <section style={{height: "100vh"}}></section>
    <section style={{height: "100vh"}}>
      Scroll here?
    </section>
    <section style={{height: "100vh"}}></section>
  </>);
}
export default ViewTwo;
```

I'm using react-router-dom-v6

Answer (score 5):

Give the sections you want to target and scroll to `id` attributes. Pass a target id in route state. Use a `useEffect` hook to target the element and scroll it into view.

Example:

```
const ViewOne = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // From react-router v6
  return (
    <p
      onClick={() => {
        navigate("/viewtwo", { state: { targetId: "section2" } });
      }}
    >
      Link to section two, in view two
    </p>
  );
};
```

...

```
const ViewTwo = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { targetId } = state || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById(targetId);
    if (el) {
      el.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }, [targetId]);

  return (
    <>
      <section id="section1" style={{ height: "100vh" }}></section>
      <section id="section2" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        Scroll here?
      </section>
      <section id="section3" style={{ height: "100vh" }}></section>
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    ...
    <Route path="/viewone" element={<ViewOne />} />
    <Route path="/viewtwo" element={<ViewTwo />} />
    ...
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit react-change-view-and-then-scroll-to-element]

Comment: Nice and concise answer! Love it and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

you can use "useRef" to scroll to that position with click event or try useEffect for scroll to that position after component rendered.

```
const ViewTwo = () => {
    const scroller = useRef(null)
    const executeScroll = () => scroller.current.scrollIntoView()    

    return (
      <>
        <section style={{height: "100vh"}}></section>
        <section ref={scroller} style={{height: "100vh"}}>
          Scroll here?
        </section>
         <button onClick={executeScroll}> Click to scroll </button> 
        <section style={{height: "100vh"}}></section>
      </>);
    }
    export default ViewTwo;
```